# Matlab - How to illustrate the percentage growth by background colour ? [of a timeseries chart]

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot a timeseries chart:

Sample data:

```
datetime = pd.date_range(start = '01/03/2019', periods = 60)  #60 days = 2 months
data = [2000]
for i in range (29):
    data.append(data[-1]*1.05)                #first 30 days - growth 5%
for i in range(30):
    data.append(data[-1]*1.15)                #last 30 days - growth 15%

plt.plot(datetime, data)
plt.show()
```

We got the figure below: [image]

So I want to have a background colour cutting in two 2 regions (2 rectangles)

- The first one covers region with 5% growth
- The second region covers region with 15% growth

I tried to do it but the difficulty is that `date` is converted into delta time by `matlab` so I could not cut it by input the day I want to cut

```
plt.xlim()
(737059.05, 737123.95)      #delta time

plt.ylim()
(-25153.66313846143, 572226.92590769)
```

Please help me in an easy way so in future I could cut in any area like 5 days, 10 days , 15 days depending on the data.

Comment: how is this question related to MATLAB? Maybe you got confused with matplotlib?

Comment: I removed the MATLAB tag. @Chau please add it back if it's really needed (but then explain in your question)

Answer (score 0):

You can work with `DateTime` objects, as long as you are not trying to mix and match the internal representation used by `matplotlib` (the one you see when you do `plt.xlim()`) and `DateTime` values.

```
d = pd.date_range(start = '01/03/2019', periods = 60)  #60 days = 2 months
data = [2000]
for i in range (29):
    data.append(data[-1]*1.05)                #first 30 days - growth 5%
for i in range(30):
    data.append(data[-1]*1.15)                #last 30 days - growth 15%

cutoff = 30
cutoff_date = d[0]+cutoff*d.freq
plt.figure()
plt.plot(d, data)
plt.axvline(cutoff_date,ls='--',color='k')
plt.axvspan(xmin=d[0],xmax=cutoff_date, facecolor='r', alpha=.5)
plt.axvspan(xmin=cutoff_date,xmax=d[-1], facecolor='g', alpha=.5)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]